# Cannot get value from second call of time.clock() in Python

Tags: python, time

I am trying to calculate the time taken between two function calls.

```
import time

class timer():
    def __init__(self)
        self.start_time = 0
        self.stop_time = 0

    def start_stream(self):
        self.start_time = time.clock()

    def stop_stream(self):
        self.stop_time = time.clock()
        print ("Time elapsed: %s % self.stop_time - self.start_time)

start_stream()
stop_stream()
```

I am always allowed to read/print `time.clock()` the first time, but when trying to save the stop time I get

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'clock'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those supposed to be instance methods? If so, where's the `class` definition and the `self` arguments to `start_...` and `stop_stream`? If not, why is one called `__init__`? Where's the rest of the code - it looks like you're assigning some integer to the name `time` at some point, shadowing the module.

Comment: Additionally: is this the code you're actually using? The above will give you a Syntax Error since you're missing parenthesis in your functino definition ( i.e `def a():`, not `def a:` )

Comment: I just tried writing the absolutely necessary code snippets, sorry for that. Why is this voted for close as off topic?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen: 4 votes for: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere *else* in the code you have assigned an integer to global name `time`. This happens after calling `start_stream()`, but before calling `stop_stream()`.

The answer is quite simple: use a different global name for that integer value, or try to avoid using a global for that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think couple of mistake are there here, i have modified the code a bit

```
import time

class Stop_watch():

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = 0
        self.stop_time = 0

    def start_stream(self):
        self.start_time = time.clock()

    def stop_stream(self):
            self.stop_time = time.clock()
            print ("Time elapsed: %s"% (self.stop_time - self.start_time))
```

call this module in your function and use it.